# jQuery File Upload: how to change the upload url dynamically

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm trying to use the blueimp [jQuery File Upload](http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/) in my project. It suits my needs fairly well but I need to change the url files are uploaded to dynamically after the plugin is created and configured. I've done a good deal of investigation, but, unfortunately, found nothing useful. In general, I have a button to choose files and fileupload action covering the actual upload. The basic creation looks like this:

```
 $('[upload-button]').fileupload(new FileUploadConfig())
```

And configuration itself:

```
 function FileUploadConfig() {

     // is set to a unique value for each file upload
     this.url = 'temporary';
     this.fileInput = $('[upload-button]');

     //... some other code
 }
```

The thing I need to do is change the url in this config and then call `data.submit()`. I've found out, that this configuration is saved using `$.data()` and tried to solve the problem with such code

```
// get the current fileupload configuration
var config = $.data($('[upload-button]').get(0), 'fileupload');

// change the url configuration option
config.options.url = file.link;

//send a file
data.submit();
```

However, this does not work the way I wanted.

Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Comment: I need to change url (parameter) after hit the submit button specially after first submit is success.. because, I need to group uploaded files into one package... I can handle with session, but the problem is sometime user open more than one tab browser.

Answer (score 29):

Just capturing this here for posterity.

In the current jQuery-upload rev, override the add(evt,data) function and set the url property of the the data object:

```
fileupload({
   add: function(e, data) {
      data.url = 'customURL'
      ...
   },
   ...
}
```

Comment: Soooo simple. The perfect solution!

Comment: This changes the URL path where php files are located. This doesn't change the PATH where the UPLOAD files go.
E.g. Itsn't not possible , if I need only 1 server side script and depending on user selectable options, the files are uploaded to different directories on server.

Comment: Fair enough. Maybe not the exact answer to the OP, but it gets you one step closer. In my case I wasn't concerned about changing the path but the endpoint (as different resource types went to different endpoints).

Comment: This worked great for me. According to the docs you can actually override any of the options that you pass when creating the widget in the first place, very useful.

Comment: Just perfect! I don't understand why this comment isn't marked as 'Answered'. Anyway.... thanks.

Comment: great and thanks, this make url  of file uploader very dynamic

Comment: How do I set the header before the request?

Comment: Make sure to do a `data.submit();` inside your function, else it won't get submitted to the server. Also, here is the documentation for the [add](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Options#add) method.

Answer (score 4):

I've accomplished this when I wanted to have a file upload to a url with a different id param by setting `autoupload` to `true` and binding the `fileuploadstart` callback:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(function () {
        'use strict';
        $('#fileupload').fileupload({
            url: 'originalurl/dest/1'
            autoUpload: true            
        }).bind('fileuploadadd', function (e, data) {
            var that = $(this).data('fileupload');              
            that.options.url = 'originalurl/dest/' + $("#selctedlocation").val();

        });
    });
```

Comment: Can you explains this a bit? Like where you put this script and such. I have successfully been able to upload to different directories using php but the download/delete stops functioning.  And I don't want to have to post/get to get the new directory variable, I would much rather use jquery/javascript.

Comment: not working, even bafter replacing
var that = $(this).data('fileupload');  
by
var that = $(this).data('blueimp-fileupload');

Answer (score 4):

You need to **bind** the **fileuploadadd** event.

Suppose you saved the dynamic url in an hidden input called "dynamicURL" then you should do this:

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
    // Other options here
}).bind('fileuploadadd', function (e, data) {
    data.url = $('input[name="dynamicURL"]').val();
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to add **.bind('fileuploadsubmit')** part. See example below:

```
function fnFileUpload(id, urlFunc, successurl) {
    $(id).fileupload({
        url: urlFunc(),
        dataType: 'json',
        maxFileSize: 10000000,
        singleFileUploads: true,
        done: function (e, data) {
            $(this).fileupload('option', 'url', urlFunc());
            if (data.result.respType == 'S') {
                window.location.href = successurl;
            } else {
                toastr.error(data.result.respDesc, data.result.respTitle);
                var progress = 0;
                $('#progress .progress-bar').css(
                    'width',
                    progress + '%'
                );
            }
        },
        progressall: function (e, data) {
            var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
            $('#progress .progress-bar').css(
                'width',
                progress + '%'
            );
        }
    }).bind('fileuploadsubmit', function (e, data) {
        $(this).fileupload('option', 'url', urlFunc());
    });
}
```

Comment: A beginner in `React` here...I had the url taken from the store but `jquery` was still using the wrong one from the initial state...adding this `bind` function to the fileupload and calling my own urlFunc() which is getting the url from the state fixed my issue, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In addition to davbryn's answer:
This string

var that = $(this).data('fileupload');

should be replaced by this

var that = $(this).data('blueimpFileupload');

Comment: This would be more suitable as a comment on davbryn's answer.

Comment: This does is correct however changing the option doesn't seem to get us anywhere as it looks like it happens too late in the chain

Answer (score 1):

Here's a general example how you might do this:

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
    url: initial_url,
    done: function (e, data) {
        $(this).fileupload('option', 'url', new_url);
    }
});
```

I use this to change the URL based on the result returned by the upload script, so I set new_url = data.result.new_url in the beginning of the done callback.

Answer (score 0):

To add to davbryn's answer:

I think the event you're binding to should be on a fileuploadadd as fileuploadstart does not give you any data, it just gives you an event.

https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Options

Answer (score 0):

This should do it, (similar to @Aneon's answer) seems to work for me:

```
var file = { link: "http://thenewurl" };

// I used a form element to create the fileupload widget
$('[upload-button]').fileupload("option", "url", file.link);

// Submit the form
$('[upload-button]').submit();
```

Submitting the form at any point after this function call will use the new url

(my code submits as soon as the image is selected, haven't tested the manual submit call).

Answer (score 0):

Unregister the plugin from the element and then register it again with a new URL.

```
$('#pictureUpload, #pictureUpload *').unbind().removeData();

$('#pictureUpload').fileupload({
...
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Hi there seems to be a simpler way to do it. I've put my code below.
The base version of uplodify is from here
http://www.startutorial.com/articles/view/21

Now what I've done is I am getting the values for **folder** from a variable. And then I load the uploadify function everytime I click the lists item below, these list items are foldernames inside the root upload directory. So when i click them i get that name and append it to the actual folder path and call the uploadify again.

But then if i keep calling it again and again, there will be more browse buttons appeding on the screen so I just removed the element #file_uploadUploader before calling the uploadify. So i guess the problem is solved. at least for me :)

Been searching for this for the past two days but finally feels good to solve it myself. B-)

---

HTML

```
<input id="file_upload" name="file_upload" type="file" />
```

- jerry1
- jerry3
- jerry2

---

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var uploadfer = 'uploads/jerry2';


$("ul li").click(function(){
uploadfer = "uploads/"+$(this).text()+"/";
alert(uploadfer);

$('#file_uploadUploader').remove();

$('#file_upload').uploadify({
'uploader'  : 'js/uploadify.swf',
'script'    : 'upload.php',
'cancelImg' : 'js/cancel.png',
'folder'    : uploadfer,
'auto'      : true
});


});

$('#file_upload').uploadify({
'uploader'  : 'js/uploadify.swf',
'script'    : 'upload.php',
'cancelImg' : 'js/cancel.png',
'folder'    : uploadfer,
'auto'      : true
});




});
```