# File Upload send to different urls depending on type

Tags: javascript, file, coffeescript, jquery-file-upload

I'm using Jquery File Upload and I have some coffeescript that looks like:

```
$('.fileupload').fileupload
dataType: "json"
add: (e, data) ->
    file = data.files[0]
    types = /(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i

    if (types.test(file.type) || types.test(file.name))
      data.submit()
    else
      alert("Oops, " + file.name + " is not a supported filetype")
  progress: (e, data) ->
  done: (e, data) ->
```

Basically, what I want to do is send to different urls based on what type of file is uploaded. For example, if a pdf is uploaded I'd like to send it to `www.website.com/process/pdf` whereas if it's a png/gif/jpeg send it to `www.website.com/process/image`.

Is this possible client side with jQuery File Upload?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the data object

```
$('.fileupload').fileupload
  dataType: "json"
  add: (e, data) ->
       file = data.files[0]
       types = /(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i
       pdf = /(\.|\/)(pdf)$/i

       if (types.test(file.type) || types.test(file.name))
         data.url = 'www.website.com/process/image'
         data.submit()
       else if (pdf.test(file.type) || pdf.test(file.name))
         data.url = 'www.website.com/process/pdf'
         data.submit()
       else
         alert("Oops, " + file.name + " is not a supported filetype")
  progress: (e, data) ->
  done: (e, data) ->
```

[jQuery File Upload: how to change the upload url dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12987066/jquery-file-upload-how-to-change-the-upload-url-dynamically)